# Skipping the Home Realm Discovery Page or microsoft sign-in page in Azure AD Enterprise application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I registered one existing .NET application in Azure AD enterprise application for SSO. When i access this application using external URL, it prompts me for Microsoft Sign-in. Is there a way to avoid Microsoft Sign-in page? In few online article, i found to pass "domain_hint" in sign-in URL. Let me know if there is as way to setup domain hint in sign-in URL while registering enterprise app.

Comment: I found the solution on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-authentication-for-federated-users-portal   There are 2 options to skip MS login page. For legacy applications, Option#2 - create custom policy and then assign it to service principal name of application, works very well

Answer (score 1):

You can enable true single sign-on through the process highlighted in this Microsoft document (published one week ago). You can use a domain-joined device so that the users can sign on silently and do not need to enter a username and password. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso

Please see the quick start guide as well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso-quick-start

Answer (score 1):

The way you make use of Domain_Hint will depend on a few details about your application -

1. What protocol you use to talk to your Azure AD?

   Depending on the protocol, you'll need to **pass the domain hint in the sign in URL for your application** as shown below:

   - WS-Federation: whr=contoso.com in the query string.
   - SAML: Either a SAML authentication request that contains a domain
     hint or a query string whr=contoso.com.
   - Open ID Connect: A query string domain_hint=contoso.com.
2. Whether your application is single-tenant or multi-tenant?

   - If it's single tenant, then it's simple - pass the domain hint for domain of one tenant that uses this application.
   - If it's multi tenant, then it needs to be conditional and you need to know the tenant before hand so you can pass the hint correctly to sign-in URL. For example, if the URL hit by each tenant is different, then that could help you.. Look at this part in the Microsoft documentation..

> For example, the application "largeapp.com" might enable their
>   customers to access the application at a custom URL
>   "contoso.largeapp.com." The app might also include a domain hint to
>   contoso.com in the authentication request.

Here are the 2 best Microsoft documentation Links on this topic that I came across:

- **[Domain Hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-authentication-for-federated-users-portal#domain-hints)**
- **[Using Azure AD to land users on their custom login page from within your app](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Using-Azure-AD-to-land-users-on-their-custom-login-page-from/ba-p/243900)**

Comment: Has anyone managed to decipher what the technical requirements are for the "SAML authentication request that contains a domain hint" option? Not talking about the query string, what do we do to implement domain hint within SAML?

Comment: Never mind I found it in that second link, thanks!
`<samlp:Scoping>
<samlp:IDPList>
<samlp:IDPEntry ProviderID="https://contoso.com" Name=”contoso.com”/>
</samlp:IDPList>
</samlp:Scoping>`